Socket.io not working after deployment on render.com
https://github.com/santukumar01/Mern-chat-app
I have deployed a MERN stack chat application on Render.com, and while basic functionalities like login and registration are working fine, the real-time chat functionality is failing. The application works as expected locally, but not after deployment.
Below type of error I get.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
index-Q4Sg5fsh.js:428
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OxY6Y47
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Help me to achieve real-time functionality.
I expect to send and receive all chats in real.
If you can help me with notification and typing functionality that would be great.
but every time I refresh the page then I am able to see the new  chat msg
Deployed link: https://mern-chat-app-q2n6.onrender.com

I can't comment so writing it here
You might want to update your cors settings for deployment
    cors: {
        // at line 47
        origin: "http://localhost:5173"  // frontend server
    }


can you please  elaborate i am not understanding what change you want to make in this line of code. before deployment  this is react frontend port .

During devlopment, you are allowing "localhost:5173" to make a connection, but after deployment, the client changes to "https://mern-chat-app-q2n6.onrender.com/" or whatever your deployment link is, so you need to add your deployment link to the cors.
